# How to create a dictionary from a list of keys and a dictionary of values in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of key: value pairs and a list of keys as below:

```
dict1 = {'a':(1, 2), 'b':(2,2), 'c':(3,3), 'd':(4,4)}
list1 = ['a', 'c']
```

I now want to create a new dictionary that only contains the key:value pairs taken from list1. So the end result is list2 below:

```
list2 = {'a':(1, 2), 'c':(3,3)}
```

Help would be much appreciated. I'm currently using python 2.5.4 if that makes any difference?

Thank you in advance. Tom

Comment: 2.5? That's *old*. Consider upgrading to 2.7, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

one nice expression, even in 2.5 you have a simple solution

```
dict((k, dict1[k]) for k in list1)
```

`dict` has an initializer that takes an iterable of tuples.  The inner expression produces one tuple at a time, looking over the keys in `list1` and getting the values from `dict1`

The above will result in a `KeyError` if `list1` contains a key not in `dict1`, if that's the case then the below will work by looking at the keys in the dict and checking for its presence in `list1`

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in dict1.iteritems() if k in list1)
```

Comment: Thanks that is perfect. And thanks to everyone else in this thread for helping out a newbie.

Comment: @TomCee, please accept the answer if you think it resolved your query

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
dict2 = {}
for key in list1:
    dict2[key] = dict1[key]
```

(I renamed `list2` to `dict2`, it seemed to make more sense).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
new_dict = {}
for i in list1:
    new_dict[i] = dict1[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple loop:

```
result = {}

for item in list1:
    result[item] = dict1[item]
```

Or, in 2.7+, with a dict comprehension:

```
result = {key: value
          for key, value in dict1.items()
              if key in list1}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do something simple like:

```
for item in list1:
    list2[item] = dict1[item]
```